# Serializing a Vec<u8> to CBOR byte string in Rust using serde_cbor

Tags: rust, serde, cbor

I want to encode `Vec<u8>` as CBOR byte string using `serde_cbor`. I tried the following code:

```rust
use serde_cbor::{to_vec}

let data = vec![0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab];
let encoded_data = to_vec(&data)?;
println!("encoded_data: {:x?}", encoded_data);
```

Which generates the following output:

```sh
encoded_data: [86, 1, 18, 23, 18, 45, 18, 67, 18, 89, 18, ab]
```

This means that all elements are encoded as single integers. However, I want to encode the vector as a CBOR byte string, i.e:

```
46              # bytes(6)
   0123456789AB # "\x01#Eg\x89\xAB"
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`serde_bytes` crate](https://crates.io/crates/serde_bytes) and [`serde_bytes::Bytes`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_bytes/struct.Bytes.html) and do `to_vec(&Bytes::new(&data[..]))?` instead.